# Terminal quasi-affine varieties?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $U$ be a normal, irreducible, quasi-affine variety over the algebraically
closed field $k$ and consider the ring $A = \mathscr{O}(U)$ of regular
functions on $U$. Write $Max(A)$ for the topological space of maximal ideals 
of $A$ (in the Zariski topology). Let $V\subset Max(A)$ be the union of all open subsets
of the form $Max(A_f)$ where is $f\in A\setminus\{0\}$ is such that  $A_f$ is
a finitely generated $k$-algebra. Is it always the case that $V$ is quasi-affine?
i.e. We know from the definition that $V$ is locally Noetherian. But is it always
Noetherian?